# About SQFlite Database in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Database Class

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_project/instructors/instructors.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;
  static Database _database;

  String istrcuctTable = 'instruct_table';
  String colID = 'id';
  String colName = 'name';
  String colPass = 'password';

  DatabaseHelper._createInstance(); // Named constructor to create instance of DatabaseHelper

  factory DatabaseHelper() {
    if (_databaseHelper == null) {
      _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper
          ._createInstance(); // This is executed only once, singleton object
    }
    return _databaseHelper;
  }

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await initializeDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
    // Get the directory path for both Android and iOS to store database.
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = directory.path + 'notes.db';

    // Open/create the database at a given path
    var notesDatabase =
        await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
    return notesDatabase;
  }

  void _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $istrcuctTable($colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $colName TEXT, '
        '$colPass TEXT)');
  }

  // Insert Operation: Insert a Note object to database
  Future<int> insertNote(Instructor instructor) async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result = await db.insert(istrcuctTable, instructor.toMap());
    return result;
  }
}


Main Class

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_project/instructors/instructors.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_project/utils/database_helper.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passController = TextEditingController();
  int result;
  Instructor note;
  DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  String name;
  String password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Form(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: nameController,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: passController,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Login'),
            onPressed: () async {
              _databaseHelper.insertNote(note);
            })
      ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

Error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toMap' was called on null. E/flutter (
>   2893): Receiver: null E/flutter (2893): Tried calling: toMap()

I have created the database and insert operation but when i call insert operation it is giving an error that InsertNote method was called on null.

Comment: The singleton pattern parts of your implementation look complex. Singleton pattern bad! Better to use dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

The error means `instructor` is null when call `instructor.toMap()` 
Because you do not init `note` with any value so it is `null` now

```
Instructor note;
```

When call below code, you actually pass a `null` to `insertNote`

```
onPressed: () async {
          _databaseHelper.insertNote(note);
        })
```

You can do

```
Instructor note = Instructor();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not set value to note(Instructor) so the note is null so whenever you call any function upon null it will give this error(note(null).toMap();
so you have to set data before performing operation
as

```
note=Instructor();//set propery as you defined in the Instructor class
```

and also you have to await onPressed as

```
onPressed: () async {
      await _databaseHelper.insertNote(note);
    })
```